# Getting cross-domain errors when using angularjs within flex (web control), and attempting to load templates/json (local files)

Tags: javascript, apache-flex, angularjs, cross-domain, local-files

Let me give you a bit of history on what I'm trying to do.

I'm using a Flex application, as a container for a web app. So within this Flex app, it has a web controller, which loads a full fledged `Angularjs` application. All the files are stored locally within the Flex app.

When I attempt to run it, it cannot load any of the templates; they are loaded using the $routeProvider, and data is pulled using the $http.get.

The core problem is that it's not allowing me to pull local files using JavaScript, even though it's being run off the file-system (not using a web server).

I also tested it on Chrome, and have the same exact issue - giving the following error.

`Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

With Chrome, it can be fixed using `--allow-file-access-from-files`, but can't figure out how to get it working via the Flex/Flash web controller.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm confused.  Are you building an AIR Desktop app?  IF so, then Flex should have no cross domain issues.  If you are building a browser based app; what does it mean to use a Flex Application as a container for a web app?

Comment: It's a desktop app, which shouldn't have any issues, but it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you probably can't. I don't know what engine Flex wraps in it's web controllers, but the reason you are bumping in to this is security.

It's in place for good reason, it's to prevent JS from having direct access to your file system.

I would suggest one of two workarounds.

- Bundle a simple webserver. For example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/530787/simple-http-web-server
- Modify the AngularJS App (and possibly $routeProvider) to use the [new File API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/)
- It's a bit of a hassel but copy all the contents of your template in to the main file in `<script type="text/ng-template" id="some-id"></script>`

Comment: The restrictions of the project don't permit me to have any sort of web server running. So there is no way for me to turn off the security restrictions, as there is in Chrome? It's using web-kit after all, so there has to be a way. As a stand alone application, I should have complete control over the web view/controller. And apologies, as I'm pretty new to Flex.

Comment: I think the limitation is in the JavaScript specs, and the Chrome application (not webkit and/or V8 JS engine) offers away to override that specific restriction. Remember that Chrome and webkit is not the same. So flex needs to offer a similar override as Chrome does.

Comment: And Flex doesn't offer any sort of customizations? Are there any other web views/controllers that I can use other than `mx:html`? There has to be some parameters that I can pass in there. Just seems so limiting.

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't already done so. Try setting up a [crossdomain](http://curtismorley.com/2007/09/01/flash-flex-tutorial-how-to-create-a-crossdomainxml-file/) policy for your application.

The problem is definitely due to [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing), the browser enforces this security constraint. In your case the browser is the flex web control.

You may not be able to get around this problem without using a web server. When the request is made for a file, the Cross Origin Resource Sharing policy will not allow the resource to be loaded without prior authorization from the host serving the file, This authorization comes in the form of an http header such as the following:

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`

Comment: Yeah, I tried setting that up, but it doesn't work without a web server, as you said.

Comment: You may be able to add the origin header to the http request via `$http.defaults.headers.common["origin"] = 'somedomain'; ` although you need to also somehow spoof the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` on the response to the initial request. However, That is not going to be so easy. May I ask why the requirement that no web server be use? Making http calls to load files in javascript needs some sort of web server there is no getting around that. It could however be a very simple web server. Even one you write yourself with node.js or some other language.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you could try to use $http.jsonp instead of $http.get, although you may have to change angularJS code....

Comment: That wouldn't change the way that the `$routeProvider` accesses the files, though.

Comment: I meant that you should change also the behaviour of $routeProvider in AngularJS. I have had to do some similar changes to be able to get template via jsonp.
I know it's not the best way, but it's the only one I've found that works.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. The problem with that, is that I'd have to update AngularJS every time they have an update. The reason I am creating it as a Web App within Flex, is so we can reuse that functionality when we decide to move it to a truly web based platform.

Comment: Yes, that's the main problem I have also found, but right now it's the only solution I've found to my problem. I will follow this question just in case a solution is given that could fit also in my problem

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are at least 2 implementations of rendering a webpage within Flex.  I quickly checked the docs for [StageWebView](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS901d38e593cd1bac3ef1d28412ac57b094b-8000.html) and found that the file:// uri scheme allows for Local XMLHttpRequests (basically what $http.get is doing).

Comment: I checked out StageWebView, but it lacks the functionality needed for communicating from JavaScript back to the Flex AIR app, and vice versa.